# Looking for something like a Lag function but more complex (SQL)

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Im racking my brain about how to do this and I dont think its possible but not sure what to even search for. So the below is a subset of the data (using example numbers)

[image: Original Dataset]

and I want to use like a lag function to pull the value down then multiply by % column and have something like the below (using the new calculated value each time)

[image: Final Dataset]

I have a feeling its not possible but fingers crossed. Using Redshift if it helps

Thanks in Advance

Comment: So like a rolling value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amazon Redshift is based on Postgresql, and even if there are some differences (cmp. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html), it does include the `lag()` function (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html).

So your statement should probably look something like this (works in postgres)

```
UPDATE yourtable
   SET number = (q1.percentage * q1.prevnumber)
  FROM (SELECT Months, percentage, lag(number) OVER (ORDER BY Months) as prevnumber 
          FROM yourtable) q1
 WHERE yourtable.Months = q1.Months AND yourtable.Months > 0;
```

You can also include a condition to only update those fields that do not have a value yet by adding something like `AND Number IS NULL` to the last `WHERE` clause. And if you have multiple years, you need to take that into account in your ordering, of course.

Have a look at these two SO posts for more detailed discussions and examples:

[Is there a way to access the "previous row" value in a SELECT statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/710212/is-there-a-way-to-access-the-previous-row-value-in-a-select-statement)

[PostgreSQL update query with "lag()" window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49036595/postgresql-update-query-with-lag-window-function)

EDIT: This query will not update all rows in a single pass, as the query is based on the original table entries and on updating the row of Month 10 will have a NULL value as one of the factors of the multiplication (number from Month 9).

There are different approaches you can use to reach your desired result. I have added two examples below. Both work in postgres and should also work in redshift:

(1) You can repeat the above `UPDATE` statement the appropriate number of times using a `WHILE` loop. The following function iteratively updates the table until no more rows exist where `number` is `NULL`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_numbers() RETURNS void AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM yourtable WHERE number IS NULL) > 0 LOOP        
        UPDATE yourtable
           SET number = (q1.percentage * q1.prevnumber)
          FROM (SELECT Months, percentage, lag(number) OVER (ORDER BY Months) as prevnumber 
                  FROM yourtable) q1
         WHERE yourtable.number IS NULL
               AND yourtable.Months = q1.Months 
               AND yourtable.Months > 0;
    END LOOP;
END;   
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

(2) You can use a `CURSOR` to loop through the individual rows in which `number` is `NULL` and update each of them one at a time:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_numbers() RETURNS void AS 
$BODY$
DECLARE
    rec record;
    prev numeric;
    cur cursor for (SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE number IS NULL ORDER BY Months) FOR UPDATE;
BEGIN
    FOR rec in cur LOOP
        SELECT prevnumber INTO prev FROM (SELECT Months, percentage, lag(number) OVER (ORDER BY Months) as prevnumber  
                    FROM yourtable) q1 where q1.months = rec.months;
        UPDATE yourtable
            SET number = (percentage * prev)
            WHERE CURRENT of cur;
    END LOOP;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

Calling either of these two with

```
SELECT update_numbers();
```

updates all rows of your example table.

Comment: Just tested the above (so in my example month 9) but when it tries to update row 10, month 9 current value is blank so it doesnt do anything? there doesnt seem to be a way of saying once that 9 is calculated use that for row 10 (unless i repeat this code x amount of times until they are all populated?